# Java Basic Pattern regex (Fully example)

Tags: java

Maybe I am not seeing the issue, I have been stuck for quite some time.
I don't understand why my regex does not work. I want to use the wildcards.

1st * -> region

2nd * -> account number

3rd * -> API ID

4th * -> stage ID

5th * -> HTTP Method

6th * -> URL, can be /user , /user/info , /user/info/somethingelse

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String methodArn = "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-1:123456:foo/test/GET/user/info";
    String permission = "arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:*/*/*/*";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(permission);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(methodArn);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println("MATCHES");
    } else {
     System.out.println("NOT MATCHES");
    }
}
```

Can you please tell me why this code executes NOT MATCHES. I was excepting it to match

Comment: `*` doesn't work on its own; it means 0 or more instances of the preceding thing; in your regex, that would be `:`.

Comment: `:/` <- This is in your regex, but the String you try to match doesn't contain any colon followed by a slash.

Comment: The supposed regex that you are using there actually looks like a UNIX-style file name pattern; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming).  Regex use a different syntax; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression.  I recommend that you find and **read** a tutorial on regexes.  Or at least, read the summary of the Java regex syntax in the `Pattern` [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: Try `String permission = "arn:aws:execute-api:.*:.*:.*/*/*/*"`

Answer (score 0):

No need for explicit regexes really, just `String.split` will do the job:

```
public class Tokenizer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String methodArn = "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-1:123456:foo/test/GET/user/info";
        String[] regAcc = methodArn.split(":", 4)[3].split(":", 3);
        System.out.printf("Region = %s%n", regAcc[0]);
        System.out.printf("Account number = %s%n", regAcc[1]);
        String[] apiIdstageIdhttpMethodUrl = regAcc[2].split("/", 4);
        System.out.printf("API ID = %s%n", apiIdstageIdhttpMethodUrl[0]);
        System.out.printf("Stage ID = %s%n", apiIdstageIdhttpMethodUrl[1]);
        System.out.printf("Http method = %s%n", apiIdstageIdhttpMethodUrl[2]);
        System.out.printf("URL = %s%n", apiIdstageIdhttpMethodUrl[3]);
    }
}
```